# Is the default ("automatic") ordering for factors a part of the R specification? Alphabetical? Same on all platforms?

Tags: r

Sometimes we can be tempted to import some data `x` into **R** with e.g. `read.table`, and then modify its levels using `levels(x$V1) <- c(...)`. Columns are originally imported into factors if we don't use the `as.is` option nor do specify `colClasses="character"`. We can contemplate doing the transformation of the levels simultaneously on all columns of a large dataframe, but then we want to make sure that all these columns (that we suppose here to be containing the same type of data, e.g. the same levels overall) have levels ordered in the very same way.

My multiple-entry question is the following:

1. Is the sorting order part of the specification of the **R** language, so is it platform-independent?
2. Is this some kind of alphabetical sorting, and if yes, according to which alphabet?

See for instance:

```
> x = as.factor(c("3","$$$av","1","2","^ab", "^ba", "3","aba","4","-ab","ba",'3',"ba"))
> x
 [1] 3     $$$av 1     2     ^ab   ^ba   3     aba   4     -ab   ba    3     ba   
Levels: 1 2 3 4 ^ab -ab aba $$$av ba ^ba
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the code of `factor`:

```
if (missing(levels)) {
    y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
    ind <- sort.list(y)
    y <- as.character(y)
    levels <- unique(y[ind])
}
```

As you see sorting is done with `sort.list`. In the documentation of that function you find:

> The sort order for character vectors will depend on the collating sequence of the locale in use: see Comparison.

And in `help("Comparison")` you can read:

> Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z. In Welsh ng may or may not be a single sorting unit: if it is it follows g. Some platforms may not respect the locale and always sort in numerical order of the bytes in an 8-bit locale, or in Unicode code-point order for a UTF-8 locale (and may not sort in the same order for the same language in different character sets). Collation of non-letters (spaces, punctuation signs, hyphens, fractions and so on) is even more problematic.

So, it's dependent on the locale and to some extent platform-dependent.

Comment: Thanks for your very good answer! At least it clearly shows that the ordering is NOT dependent on the order of the data as seen in the factor itself, and so will be the same on all columns of the same df (provided that all levels are present in each column).