# Why does as.factor() on unicode strings return different results for every operating system?

Tags: r, unicode

Why does this code: `as.factor(c("\U201C", '"3', "1", "2", "\U00B5"))`, return different orderings of factor levels on every operating system?

On Linux:

`> as.factor(c("\U201C",'"3', "1", "2","\U00B5"))
[1] "  "3 1  2  µ 
Levels: µ " 1 2 "3`

On Windows:

`> as.factor(c("\U201C",'"3', "1", "2","\U00B5"))
[1] "  "3 1  2  µ 
Levels: "3 " µ 1 2`

On Mac OS:

`>as.factor(c("\U201C",'"3', "1", "2","\U00B5"))
[1] "  "3 1  2  µ 
Levels: "3 " 1 2 µ`

I had some students submit an RMardkown assignment that contained `as.numeric(as.factor(dat$var))`. Now granted this is not a good way to code, but the inconsistency in output lead to much confusion and wasted time.

Comment: As weird as it is, it's the same on FreeBSD as on OS X. No idea where the difference comes from, but knowing where the similarities between OS X and FreeBSD are might help?

Comment: I don't have an answer but it actually might stem from the `sort` function in R. Looking at the code for `as.factor`, you have `levels <- sort(unique.default(x))`. I have tried `sort` on Windows and Mac OS on your vector and get different sortings.

Comment: It's a locale thing, specifically `LC_COLLATE`. You can set it with `Sys.setlocale` to see what's happening.

Comment: You're right. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075265/is-the-default-automatic-ordering-for-factors-a-part-of-the-r-specification.

Comment: Thankyou both. I can see the difference in locale settings, but unfortunately I cannot change them to get the same collation behaviour. I get a warning like: "OS reports request to set locale to "en_US.UTF-8" cannot be honored".

Comment: It is _both_ an encoding _and_ a locale issue as explained in my answer, but since no one else has stepped up with a full answer that has gotten recognized as such, I'll first go look for a prior duplicate and then expand my answer

Answer (score 6):

It's not just Unicode and not just R; `sort` in general (as in even the *nix command `sort`) can be locale specific. Setting `LC_COLLATE` (presumably to `"C"`) via `Sys.setlocale` (as per @alistaire's comment) on all machines is required to remove the differences.

For me, on Windows (7):

```
sort(c("Abc", "abc", "_abc", "ABC"))
[1] "_abc" "abc"  "Abc"  "ABC"
```

whereas on Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 ... wow, I need to upgrade that machine) I get

```
sort(c("Abc", "abc", "_abc", "ABC"))
[1] "abc"  "_abc" "Abc"  "ABC"
```

Setting the locale as per above via

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_COLLATE", "C")
```

gives

```
sort(c("Abc", "abc", "_abc", "ABC"))
[1] "ABC"  "Abc"  "_abc" "abc"
```

on both machines, identically.

The *nix `man` page for `sort` gives the bold warning

> ```
>    *** WARNING *** The locale specified by the  environment  affects  sort
>    order.  Set LC_ALL=C to get the traditional sort order that uses native
>    byte values.
> ```

**Update:** Looks like I reproduce the issue when including Unicode characters. The issue traces back to `sort` - try sorting the vector in your example. I can't seem to change the locale (`LC_COLLATE` or `LC_CTYPE`) to `"en_AU.UTF-8"` either, which would be a potential solution.

Comment: Thanks Jono! I set the LC_COLLATE to "C" on Windows and Linux and the ordering got a little closer but is still not identical.

Comment: Can you update the MRE to show what's still not matching up? Could be a representation thing.

Comment: Updated. Unicode doesn't play nice, and it's potentially solved by changing to `UTF-8` but I can't figure out how to force it to do so.

Comment: I thought there was an `Encoding<-` function?

Answer (score 2):

The 'factor' structure expects to convert to a character value, and therefore this needs to encoded in some font or another. The default is OS-specific. Lexical sort-order follows locale.

To a useful extent @Roland's prior answer to this question nails the locale issue but not the encoding issue: [Is the default ("automatic") ordering for factors a part of the R specification? Alphabetical? Same on all platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25075265/is-the-default-automatic-ordering-for-factors-a-part-of-the-r-specification)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried changing the locale settings but am unable to solve this problem. However, given that we can trace this problem back to the `sort` function, one possible alternative is to re-define the `factor` and `as.factor` functions without the `sort` function.

```
as.factor2 <- function(x){
  if (is.factor(x)) 
    x
  else if (!is.object(x) && is.integer(x)) {
    levels <- unique.default(x) # Removed sort()
    f <- match(x, levels)
    levels(f) <- as.character(levels)
    class(f) <- "factor"
    f
  }
  else factor2(x)
}

factor2 <- function (x = character(), levels, labels = levels, exclude = NA, 
          ordered = is.ordered(x), nmax = NA) 
{
  if (is.null(x)) 
    x <- character()
  nx <- names(x)
  if (missing(levels)) {
    y <- unique(x, nmax = nmax)
    ind <- 1:length(y) # Changed from sort.list(y)
    y <- as.character(y)
    levels <- unique(y[ind])
  }
  force(ordered)
  exclude <- as.vector(exclude, typeof(x))
  x <- as.character(x)
  levels <- levels[is.na(match(levels, exclude))]
  f <- match(x, levels)
  if (!is.null(nx)) 
    names(f) <- nx
  nl <- length(labels)
  nL <- length(levels)
  if (!any(nl == c(1L, nL))) 
    stop(gettextf("invalid 'labels'; length %d should be 1 or %d", 
                  nl, nL), domain = NA)
  levels(f) <- if (nl == nL) 
    as.character(labels)
  else paste0(labels, seq_along(levels))
  class(f) <- c(if (ordered) "ordered", "factor")
  f
}
```

We can now call `as.factor2` as follows:

```
as.factor2(c("\U201C",'"3', "1", "2","\U00B5"))
# [1] “  "3 1  2  µ 
# Levels: "3 “ 1 2 µ
```

I wouldn't say that this is a solution to your problem; it's more of a workaround. Especially since this involves teaching students, I'd prefer to not re-create base R functions. Hopefully, someone else can provide a simpler solution.

Comment: This can have unexpected consequences. Some functions might assume that levels are ordered.

Comment: This would always return the factors in the order they are encountered? That seems like the best platform agnostic way to do it. I agree it's not good to rewrite base, but it happens all the time. E.g. `read_csv()` vs `read.csv()`. Incidentally this problem is probably inherited by `read.csv()`. Maybe we can get Hadley to put `as_factor()` into `Forcats`.

Comment: I'm not a fan of this answer as it means you likely lose alphabetical sort-order, which is a much more common occurrence than Unicode strings.

Comment: @MilesMcBain - `read.csv` takes an `encoding` argument which allows one to specify that the strings are `UTF-8`. Extending `forcats` to include a `fct_factor` which deals with encoding could be useful, though tricky.

Comment: @MilesMcBain, yes, it would always return the levels in the order in which they are encountered, meaning they lose their alphabetical order. As I said, I would prefer to use the base factor function, but if order really matters to you regardless of platform, then the workaround above should be good.